# Exception in a runnable appears to kill threadpool

Tags: java, exception, threadpool, runnable

I have a runnable that I want to run periodically. On a particular run, I believe the runnable encountered a null pointer, but no exception was shown on the console. After that failed run, it never runs again. I have two questions:

1. If there was a null pointer, why wasn't this shown on the console
2. How can I have the scheduled task run again in the future, even if a particular run fails?

```
scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
MyRunnable mr = new MyRunnable(this.data);
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(mr, 0, STATUS_SENDER_PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Can you please your code? Please show your `MyRunnable` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions,

1) The reason why you do not see any kind of exception is due to the fact that the `FutureTask#setException` called within `FutureTask#run` effectively swallows it. In order to be be able to log the exception you should either create a new class the extends the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and override the `afterExecute` method like so:

```
@Override
protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
    if (t == null && r instanceof Future<?>) {
        try {
            Object result = ((Future<?>) r).get();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
         } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            t = e;
         }
    }

    if (t != null) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Or directly invoke `get` on the returned `ScheduledFuture` like so:

```
var executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
var future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyRunnable(null), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

try {
    future.get();

} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

2) The easiest way of re-running the failed runnable would to do this:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

But imho this approach is not the cleanest. Properly coding your `Runnable#run` method to handle exception would be a better solution.